# Can't show anything above home directory in QFileSystemModel in Linux

Tags: linux, qt, home-directory, qfilesystemmodel

I have the following code in Qt4.8 under Linux:

```
 QFileSystemModel* dir_model = new QFileSystemModel;
 dir_model->setRootPath("/usr");
 ui->dir_tree->setModel(dir_model);
```

Instead of showing "/usr" the tree widget shows my home directory. If I provide anything above my home (like "/", "/etc", "/media") it always show my home and nothing above.
If I provide something inside my home like "/home/semen/something" it shows exactly this directory with no problems.
I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. What should I do to show for example "/media/something"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you then have to set root index for the view.

```
QFileSystemModel* dir_model = new QFileSystemModel;
QModelIndex rootIndex = dir_model->setRootPath("/usr");
ui->dir_tree->setModel(dir_model);
ui->dir_tree->setRootIndex(rootIndex);  // you are missing this step
```

Comment: It works! Thank you very much! I wonder why this simple thing is not documented properly.

Comment: It is indeed documented.. see Example Usage on http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html